# How pause a service when the activity go in pause after the "home" button?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service that look gps coordinate. I want that when the user click on the home button the gps stop to work (battery saving).

The strategy i am using is this:

```
    @Override
public void onPause() { 
    super.onPause();
    doUnbindService();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    doBindService();  
}
```

on each Activity that use the service. The problem is that each time i switch activity it stop and resume. Is there a strategy that let me have the service always up until my app is in foregroung?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an app with 3 activities that use a service to deal with the GPS. In each activity's onStart() I have code of the form

```
bindService(new Intent(..., ..., Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

and in each onStop() I have

```
unbindService(..);
```

You should find that activity 2's onStart() will execute before activity 1's onStop(). Thus only when no activities are running will the service stop.

Comment: all work good.. the solo problem is when the screen go in sleep.. gps stay alive